# Extracting last word from each line using regex

Tags: python, regex

I would like to extract the last word of each line using regex. Most of the last words are built up like this:

sfdsa AAAAB3NzaCLkc3M

gadsgadsg AAAB3NzaCl/Ezfl

dogjasdpgpds AAAB3Nza/ClBAm+4lj

I already tried:

```
lastwords = re.findall(r'\s(\w+)$', content, re.MULTILINE)
```

Comment: Can you post your expected output?

Comment: there are no spaces in your examples. How can it work?

Comment: And example input line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to try that:

```
\s*([\S]+)$
```

[Regex 101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gMIcAA/2)

Explanation:

- `\s*` zero or more whitespace characters
- `[\S]+` followed by one or more non whitespace characters
- `$` followed by end of line.

By that way, you are guaranteed to match the last occurance of whitespace characters as that will be followed by no further whitespace characters.

The reason behind your regex did not work because `\w+` only covers `A-Za-z0-9_` 
So, `/` doesn't match in two of your example.

Comment: if that works for you then you may look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Yeah sorry, stackoverflow told me to wait 10min before I can accept or upvote an answer

Comment: @RizwanM.Tuman Why you are restricting followed by no further whitespace characters after the last occurrence? Whats wrong with adding \s* at the end of the pattern like \s*([\S]+)\s*$.

Comment: @ramganesh that is a tricky question... I just followed, what the op wanted... based on his provided original regex... if he wanted otherwise may be I would have considered that , or may be not...

Comment: Answers like this are super handy with Find and Replace functionality in text editors, so I don't have to learn vi/vim/emacs. Thanks so much!