# Bash sed to find lines where the last word contains letter

Tags: regex, sed

Using only sed, I'm trying to print the lines of a file where the last word includes the letter 'd'.
The contents may look similar to:

```
Honey, I am leaving for grocery shopping. Do you want anything?
Are you well? You look exhausted.
```

after which only the second line would be printed.

I tried `sed -En '/\s*([\S]+)\b[a-zA-Z]*d[a-zA-Z]*\b\.$/p' lines.txt`

After reading  [this answer on SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49873743/12075842) My logic for my regex is that I match the last word, and then checking for any character combination in that word, asserting that a 'd' character exists, then any character combination afterwards.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, non-GNU `sed` does not support `\S`/`\s` or `\b` constructs.

You can use

```sh
sed -En '/d[[:alpha:]]*[^[:alpha:]]*$/p' file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/74TGiS):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='Honey, I am leaving for grocery shopping. Do you want anything?
Are you well? You look exhausted.'
sed -En '/d[[:alpha:]]*[^[:alpha:]]*$/p' <<< "$s"
# => Are you well? You look exhausted.
```

The `d[[:alpha:]]*[^[:alpha:]]*$` pattern matches a `d`, then zero or more letters, and then any zero or more non-letters till end of string.

Comment: How does the [[:alpha:]] work? I was not aware that you could nest combinations like that? Thank you, either way.

Comment: @EdwinCarlsson `[:alpha:]` is a POSIX character class, that is placed into a bracket expression in order to work, and `[[:alpha:]]` matches any letter. `[^...]` is a negated bracket expression, it matches any char other than the set(s)/class(es) in it, so `[^[:alpha:]]` matches any char other than a letter.